# ¿Por qué Ajax result se muestra en todos los div's dentro de un foreach?

Tags: ajax, asp.net

Estoy implementando Ajax para traer mas datos de mis productos.

Los muestro realizando un for, dentro de este ciclo inclui la llamada ajax, la cual quiero que para el item actual en el que estoy me devuelva en el div los datos, pero estos se estan generando para cada uno.

Dejo la imagen y parte del codigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.btncargar').click(function ajaxCall() {

        var idProduct = $(this).attr("data-idProduct");
     
        $.ajax

            ({
                url: '/ProductsTable/GetDesc',
                data: { id: idProduct },
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',


                success: function (result) {

                    $('.divGet').html(result);
                    

                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert(status);
                },
          
               
            });


    });



});
```

```html
 <div class="row">
                    <p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
                    </p>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
                        <div class="col-md-5 divprod" style="border-color:@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Color);">
                            <div><h2 class="titulos" style="background: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Color); "> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameProduct)</h2></div>
                            <p> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mindescription).</p>
                            <div> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })|                       
                            
                            <input data-idProduct="@item.Id"  type="button" value="More information" class="btncargar"/>
                                               
                                                    
                                <div class="divGet"></div>
                            </div>
            </div>

}

        </div>
       </div>
       </div>
</div><br>
```

Comment: Se pone en todos los divs porque `$('.divGet')` selecciona todos los divs que creas con el foreach, debes buscar crear un atributo id, donde ahí puedas entonces seleccionar el div que estés buscando

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.btncargar').click(function ajaxCall() {

        var boton = $(this);
        var idProduct = $(this).attr("data-idProduct");

        $.ajax({
            url: '/ProductsTable/GetDesc',
            data: { id: idProduct },
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (result) {
                $(boton).parent().find('.divGet').html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            }, 
        });
    });
});
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !